# Is there a way to crop an image with Raphael.js?

Tags: raphael, crop

I am trying to fit part of in image into a raphael object.
Scaling the image works perfectly, but when I try to translate it, it ends up returning the wrong part of the image.
I am scalling the image using "S1.5,1.5,0,0", that is, I am not scalling it around the middle point, so scalling it works beautifully.
But, as I try to offset the image, the resulting image fragment is offset.

Maybe there's another way to do it in Raphael.
What I am trying to accomplish is use a fragment of an image as an image object in Raphael and I need to copy a rectangle from an external image into it.
Something like:

copy original image fragment (x0 = 100, y0 = 120, width = 300, height = 250) to the image object, which has dimensions (width = 150 and 125).

I have been looking for an answer for some time, but nothing that really helps.

Edit:

The fiddle is

/w9XSf/12/

In the example above, I am grabbing a 100 x 60px area from the original image (which is 612 x 325px), and trying to display it on the output image, which is 500 x 300px.

The scale works, but the area it is grabbing is not the one I need.
It does work, if I grab from 0, 0.
But, as I move from the top left corner of the originsl image, the actual area it gives me is farther away from what I actually need :(.

Any ideas? (I have already tried swapping the order of the T and the S in the transform string).

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share the code? Or a fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Raphael, the following code creates a container, to be used to display an image, duly translated and scaled. A live version of the solution is also available at http://jsfiddle.net/s6DHf/. This is a forked version of the actual problem.

```
var outputW = 525,
    outputH = 300;
    sourceX = 100,
    sourceY = 100,
    scaleX = 1.5,
    scaleY = 1.5,
    paper = new Raphael("image", outputW, outputH),
    bgImg = paper.image("http://cdn3.whatculture.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/MAN-OF-STEEL-e1365755036183.jpg", 0, 0, 350, 200)
        .transform("t" + sourceX + "," + sourceY + "s" + scaleX +","+ scaleY + ",0,0");
```

Check the use of "s"  and "t" (in **lowercase**), which denotes relative scaling and relative translation, respectively. The problem was due to the use of "S" and "T" (in **uppercase**), which is all about absolute scaling and translation, respectively.

Raphael reference: http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.transform

Hope this helps.